# Using Smooth Scroll Polyfill with Angular 2 CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Can anyone please guide how to use Smooth Scroll Polyfill with **Angular 2 CLI**.

I tried adding below to **polyfills.ts** but it throws error on work require

```
require('smoothscroll-polyfill').polyfill();
```

I then tried adding

```
import 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
```

Though it didn't throw any error during build but when I run the project in browser it show below error on console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'scroll' on 'Window': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the Angular 2/4 solution:

Install [smoothscroll-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill) - `npm install smoothscroll-polyfill`.

Then add to your src/polyfills.ts file:

```
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill/dist/smoothscroll.js';
smoothscroll.polyfill();
```

Comment: Thank you Stas, for me this is works: 

import { polyfill } from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
polyfill();

Comment: I prefer this method as it helps keep polyfills out of my main code and satisfy my separation of concerns. Could also install the `@types/smoothscroll-polyfill` to keep linters happy, as others have suggested, but this is not essential.

Answer (score 6):

You need install the polyfill and @types

1. `yarn add smoothscroll-polyfill` or `npm install smoothscroll-polyfill`
2. `yarn add @types/smoothscroll-polyfill` or `npm install @types/smoothscroll-polyfill`

So, in your code you should init the polyfill in the component or service what you wish used this polyfill:

```
import * as smoothscroll from "smoothscroll-polyfill";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-demo',
  templateUrl: './app-my-demo.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-my-demo.css']
})
export MyClass my implements OnInit {

  constructor(
  ) {
    smoothscroll.polyfill();
   }
```

You could use in the component, for example:

```
  clickAnyThing(event:any){
    window.scroll({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
```

Comment: I much prefer @Stas' solution, as I would rather keep polyfills out of my main code. I believe the `polyfills.ts` file exists in Angular2+ projects set up from CLI.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I set it up in my `polyfills.ts` file:

```
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill/dist/smoothscroll';
smoothscroll.polyfill();
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
your_element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Comment: This used to work for me too but recently broke. Now I'm having to do it in the component like @caballerog suggests.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular cli

First install the package:

`npm install smoothscroll-polyfill`

Then add the following to angular-cli.json under apps.scripts array:

`"../node_modules/smoothscroll-polyfill/src/smoothscroll.js"`

And then try something like:

`window.scroll({ top: 400, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });`

It should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46534123/1438576  is the preferred angular solution (via polyfills.ts)

Answer (score 1):

#### #option 1

It can be included directly in the `index.html` it will run immediately and does not need to be invoked with `smoothscroll.polyfill();`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.3/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
```

#### #option 2

`npm install smoothscroll-polyfill --save`

including it in  `src/polyfills.ts`

`import 'smoothscroll-polyfill';`

or adding it to `scripts` in `.angular-cli.json` should work.

---

Importing in the Component:

```
import  { polyfill } from "smoothscroll-polyfill"

polyfill()
```

- #### #use:

`window.scroll({ top: 200, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });`

---

- #### [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy67xrww38)
- In both cases, the script will detect if the spec is natively supported and take action only when necessary.
- [smooth scroll behavior polyfill Documentation](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/)
- [MDN: scroll-behavior Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#Browser_compatibility)
- The code requires requestAnimationFrame polyfill for browsers which don't support it.

Comment: It is considered better practice to put this in `scripts` in `.angular-cli.json`, loading it from `node_modules`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but since there is a file with name polyfills.ts in angular cli project I believe polyfills should be added in this file. I came across this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42982811/2755616 but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @user663031  it is no longer considered best practice in angular _for polyfills_. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46534123/1438576

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it with Typescript then you should install

`npm install smoothscroll-polyfill @types/smoothscroll-polyfill`

OR

`yarn add smoothscroll-polyfill @types/smoothscroll-polyfill`/

Then you can use it like below

```
    import * as smoothscroll from "smoothscroll-polyfill";
    smoothscroll.polyfill();
```

---

Alternatively,
 you can include polyfill only when it is needed. you can try something below if you're using webpack, parcel or any other build system which supports dynamic imports.

```
    if (!'scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style) {
    // Wait until the Polyfills are loaded
    Promise.all([
        import('smoothscroll-polyfill'),
        import('smoothscroll-anchor-polyfill')
    ])
        // then use the modules however you want
        .then(([smoothscrollPolyfill, smoothscrollAnchorPolyfill]) => {
        // (Unlike this package, smoothscroll-polyfill needs to be actively invoked: )
        smoothscroll.polyfill();
        });
    }
```