# Javascript function in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am new to angular2. I am converting an html website into angular 2. There is a javascript `smoothscroll` function and its in an external js file. The problem is that this code and function is running fine in html but not running in angular. Maybe, I am doing some mistakes. Please guide me .

```js
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - New Age v3.3.7 (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/new-age)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */
 //scroll funtion code
!function(t){"use strict";t("a.page-scroll").bind("click",function(a){var o=t(this);t("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:t(o.attr("href")).offset().top-50},1250,"easeInOutExpo"),a.preventDefault()}),t("body").scrollspy({target:".navbar-fixed-top",offset:100}),t(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function(){t(".navbar-toggle:visible").click()}),t("#mainNav").affix({offset:{top:50}})}(jQuery);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jamalapp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- jquery linking-->

  <script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/js/jquery.filterizr.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <!--<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <link href="assets/css/hover-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans">
        


  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top">
  <app-root></app-root>





  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/js/new-age.min.js"></script>



  <script>
    $(function () {
      var selectedClass = "";
      $(".fil-cat").click(function () {
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
        $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $("#portfolio div").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("." + selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
          $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
        }, 300);

      });
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var movementStrength = 25;
      var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
      var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
      $("#about").mousemove(function (e) {
        var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
        var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
        var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 20;
        var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 70;
        $('#about').css("background-position", newvalueX + "px     " + newvalueY + "px");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

<!--this is how i am accessing it into a component-->
<li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: The html code is of indext.html

Comment: Best way is to convert your code to TS code.

You need to convert this code to angular js code. Use Typescript instead.
For example
To convert
$(".fil-cat").click(function () {});
Bind these events in the particular component where .fil-cat exist.
If it's part of the root component define click handlers there. If there is some html code that is defined inside the index file. Move it to app.component.html

Comment: This function is working fine. The problem is with scroll function code that i have in the javascript file. How do i call this function which is in external js file in any component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scroll angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092212/smooth-scroll-angular2)